# Is locking necessary when using moveToThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I searched this site and QT documentation, but could not find and direct answer for the following question:

Lets say I have a worker class with only one slot:

```
void Worker::testSlot(){
  //access data and do some calculation
}
```

Now if this slot is connected to signal from other classes running on other thread, and if queued connection is used, is it necessary to use lock (QMutexLocker) before accessing data in worker? I think it is not needed since the testSlot() is executed in one thread always (the thread in which worker is moved), and thus it is synchronized. Even if two signals were emitted from different thread at the same time, there is no way to suspend executing the slot in half-way for the first signal and start for second signal. But I am not sure about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're 100% correct.

The key bit of information is that emission of a signal connected to an object in a different thread via a queued or automatic connection results in posting a `QMetaCallEvent` to the target object. It doesn't directly result in any calls at all.

The event loop running in the thread where the target object resides has toy deliver the event to the object - you can verify that by properly overriding the `event` method and outputting a debug message when the event has the `MetaCall` type. Remember to call the base class's method in your reimplementation. Since the event loop runs synchronously, it executes the calls serially. Thus no additional serialization-of-access means are necessary. It doesn't matter what thread the meta call event was posted from - the thread per se is not used for the posting, and the event queue will look the same whether a number of events was posted from one thread, or multiple threads.

It is the `QObject::event` method that handles the `QMetaCallEvent` and executes the call. The call may be to a slot, an invokable method, a constructor/destructor, or a functor that is to execute in a given object's thread context.

Comment: But it breaks when calling the slot directly or using direct connection for signal/slot right?

Comment: @RakibulHasan Hopefully you won't ever be using a direct connection, since the default is an automatic connection, not a direct one. Calling the slot directly of course breaks things. It is only legal if the slot is thread-safe. If you write the slot, you would have to ensure it is written to be so (for example by serializing access to instance/class data). You can use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` to work around this without needing to fire a signal or implement access serialization on your own.